# How to prevent disk from going to standby

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, freeze

I have a rather new laptop (just a few months old) with a 128GB SSD where my OS is installed and a 1TB HDD where I place most heavy files. The problem I'm having with it is: after a few seconds of not accessing a file in my HDD, the disk stops spinning. Thing is, after about a minute, either a system process or my antivirus try to access the pagefile.sys of that disk, which make it start spinning; and every time it starts spinning, I get a short freeze of about half a second.

According to hdparm, the state of the disk when it's spinning is active/idle, and after a few seconds, it goes to standby until something accesses a file there. This standby state is not sleep, so changing the settings of my power options related to the disk doesn't really do anything (I did try it).

Does anyone have any idea how to keep the disk in active state so it doesn't have to start spinning every few minutes and prevent the freezes? Do I have to run a task that constantly opens a file in that disk to prevent it from going to standby?

Comment: May I know if the issue is prevent hard drives from going to sleep? If yes, please kindly check if methods in this article was helpful: [Prevent Hard Drives from Going to Sleep in Windows 10](https://technicallyeasy.net/fix-prevent-hard-drives-from-going-sleep-windows-10/#:~:text=Click%20Start%2D%3ESettings%2D%3E,plan%20you%20wish%20to%20change.)

Comment: @Sunny Sadly, that article doesn't help. As I mentioned in the question, I already tried changing my power options for the disk and the hard drive isn't external. I also don't think it's going to sleep. I believe t's going into a standby state which I think, is something intermediate between active and sleep (that's the output of running `hdparm -C /dev/hda`)